# Filter users from AD that are in Disable Mode from a CSV list of users (Disable/Enable/Mixed ) with Powershell

Tags: powershell

```
# Import the Active Directory module
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Specify the path to the CSV file
$csvPath = "C:\UsersInDsable.csv"

# Read the CSV file
$userList = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

# Create an array to store results
$results = @()

foreach ($user in $userList) {
    # Get user information by username
    $adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter { Enabled -eq $false } -Properties Name, UserPrincipalName, Enabled

    # Check if user is found
    if ($adUser) {
        # Check if the user is disabled
        $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            SamAccountName = $adUser.SamAccountName
            DisplayName = $adUser.DisplayName
            IsDisabled = -not $adUser.Enabled
        }

        # Add the result to the array
        $results += $result
    } else {
        Write-Host "User '$($user.Username)' not found in Active Directory."
    }
}
```

NOT WORKING

I tried to run the script but its stays in Red status. I need to resolve the issue

Comment: Why do you loop over `$userList` with `$user` but don't use it in your `Get-ADUser`? And btw: _Not Working_ is a very vague error description. What is red status? What do you expect from your script and what do you get instead?

Comment: What I wanted to do in general is to take a list I received of disabled users and compare it to the list I get out of Active Directory

Comment: You are using the variable `$user` in your foreach, but `$adUser` in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't use `$user` in your `Get-ADUser` call you will always get a list of all disabled users. And if/since this list is not empty, your if will always be true. So you need to incorporate your `$user` somewhere in there, e.g.:

```
$adUser = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $user.Username -and Enabled -eq $false } -Properties Name, UserPrincipalName, Enabled
```

*This is untested because I don't know what `$user` looks like.*